# Expected '}' in \u{...} escape sequence

Tags: swift, utf-8, fonts

I'm trying to put a custom font (https://andrewgioia.github.io/Mana/cheatsheet.html) into my app. I've done the apple docs instructions and confirmed that the font is usable in the storyboard etc....

But when I try to use the UTF8 representation in a string I get the following error

`Expected '}' in \u{...} escape sequence`

I am just trying to do something simple for now like:

```
let s = "\u{&#xe600;}"
```

I don't see this error in google search and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
let s = "\u{e600}"
```

Just put the hex code in the curly braces.

BTW - That's a private use area character so unless you have a special font that uses that character, don't expect to see much.

Comment: LMAO I've been stuck on that for quite some time, alright good to know I only need those 4 characters. Thanks so much!! Lifesaver!!!!

Comment: Syntax such as `&#xe600;` is for HTML or XML entities.

Comment: Still author questions is valid, your solution won't work if the code is taken from variable and that gives same error